# read full review from the dataset with the specific word that shown in wordcloud

Tags: count, nlp, sentiment-analysis, word-cloud, review

Hy! I am finding for the reviews from dataset related to those specific words that are shown in wordCloud
here is my code for visualizing  and counting for words

## **visualize wordcloud with removing stopwords**

```
stopwords=set(STOPWORDS)
stopwords.update(["car","vehicle","time","buy","new","infiniti",])
wordcloud_spam=WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords,background_color="white").generate(negitive_reviews_str)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(wordcloud_spam, interpolation = 'bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

## **count first 10 words from cloud**

```
filtered_word_spam=[word for word in negitive_reviews_str.split()if word not in stopwords]
counted_word_spam=collections.Counter(filtered_word_spam)
word_count_spam={}
for letter, count in counted_word_spam.most_common(10):
    word_count_spam[letter]=count
for i,j in word_count_spam.items():
    print('Word: {0}, count: {1}'.format(i,j))
```